# Is preimage of a point in a compact Hausdorff space under a continuous closed surjection compact?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous, closed, and surjective, can I say that for any $y\in Y$ that $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact in $X$.  Ultimately I'm trying to prove that $Y$ must be Hausdorff, but I need this for my proof and can't seem to figure out why it is true (if it is even true).  Any hints?

Just to elaborate, I know that if $Y$ is Hausdorff then $\{y\}$ is closed and hence the preimage must be compact in $X$ since $X$ is Hausdorff and $p$ is continuous.  So I do believe that my claim is true, but I can't see how to show it without assuming that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Pick $x \in p^{-1}(\{y\})$. What follows for $p(\{x\})$?

Comment: It's closed since $\{x\}$ is closed, but I don't see how that helps.  If there were only finitely many $x$ in the preimage that I could claim that the preimage is closed and hence compact, but that won't work.

Comment: Well, what _is_ $p(\{x\})$ (and hence $p^{-1}(p(\{x\}))$)?

Comment: Oh, I get it.  $\{x\}$ is closed, and since $p$ is a closed map, $p(x)=y$ is closed.  Since $y$ is closed, its preimage must be closed since $p$ is continuous and hence compact since it's a closed subset of a compact space.  Thanks!